# Air fried sweet potatoes have black dots on them

Tags: frying, sweet-potatoes

I attempted to air fry some sweet potatoes and over cooked them a bit. I noticed that they had black dots all over them which I havent seen before. Is this normal or was there something wrong with the potatoes to begin with?

[Sweet potatoes picture on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn0IE.jpg)

[a better image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwfUT.jpg)

I bought the store, pre-cut package from the veggie section.

It is on all of them (about 40 pieces) and I havent eaten any yet in case it was some type of mold or other craziness that got air fried

Comment: Can you upload a clearer picture?

Comment: @Bee should be there now

Comment: The black dots (or any visible dots) were not there on the raw sweet potatoes. It was only after cooking them they appeared.

Comment: cooking should kill any mold, so it's not a safety problem, just a taste problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are just burnt or almost-burnt spots where the sugars in the sweet potatoes caramelized a *bit* too much. It's possible the potatoes are still palatable - taste them.